# Вызов функции с аргументами из консоли

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть функция

```
def func(file, name):
    ...
```

Она принимает два аргумента, но у меня не получается вызвать эту функцию через консоль с аргументами. В консоли пишу вот так: `python main.py func(file, name)`, но результата нет.

извините, не до конца разобрался с темой, нужно сделать это через cli
Решил использовать click

Comment: Аргументы командной строки кладутся в список строк `sys.argv`, и вы должны самостоятельно в коде прочитать этот список и сделать с ним что вам нужно

Comment: Функция должна вызываться из кода или из интерактивного режима Python (например) а не из консоли.

Comment: извините, не до конца разобрался с темой, нужно сделать это через cli.

Comment: Разбор параметров командной строки в Python: https://jenyay.net/Programming/Argparse

Comment: "Решил использовать click" - параметры можно разбирать и через click, но для разбора python-подобного синтаксиса (`func(file, name)`) он не предназначен. Командная строка в принципе не очень подходит для использования python-подобного синтаксиса. Разве что передавать в кавычках, а внутри запускать через злой eval.

Comment: а если, пользуясь click, я пишу в консоли python main.py func file?

Comment: Всем большое спасибо! Разобрался с ckick, настроил cli, если я правильно понял :-).

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете передать в файл аргументы через командную строку и прочитать их с помощью из списка `sys.argv`.

Для примера я буду использовать первый переданный аргумент как имя нужной функции, а остальное как то что нужно в неё передать.

Пример кода с возможностью запуска нескольких функций из командной строки:

```
import sys 

# Доверенные методы, только их можно будет вызвать из командной строки
# Сделано для повышения безопасности
ACCESSED_METHODS = [
    "test_one",
    "test_two"
]

# Обрезаем переданные аргументы, первым всегда является путь к исполняемому файлу
args = sys.argv[1:]

# Если не передано аргументов завершаем программу
if len(args) < 1:
    print("Не передано название метода. Пример: python main.py function arg1 arg2")
    exit(1)

# Тестовые методы
def test_one(arg1: str, arg2: str, *args):
    return f"Первый метод. Переданные аргументы: {arg1, arg2, args}"

def test_two(*args):
    return f"Второй метод. Переданные аргументы: {args}"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Имя нужной функции записано в переменную func
    func = args[0]
    # Передаваемые к ней аргументы записываются в переменную func_args
    func_args = args[1:]

    if func not in ACCESSED_METHODS:
        print(f"Метода не существует или он запрещён: {func}")
        exit(1)

    # Вызываем функцию и передаём аргументы
    result = eval(func)(*func_args)

    # Результат будет выводиться в консоль
    print(result)
```

Таким образом вызывая из командной строки файл, нужно будет передать имя функции и её аргументы: `python main.py test_one 1 2 3`

Comment: Если этот код выполняется только вами и доверенными людьми, то можно использовать такое решение, если же код будет где-то в продакшене, eval лучше не использовать вообще. Или можно сначала проверять через if есть ли переданное название метода в разрешённых и уже после делать eval, чтобы избежать уязвимости в программе.

Comment: Вместо `eval(func)` лучше использовать `globals()[func]`